# Title of plot inside a shape

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add only one shape on the plot line (not on the bars), with text that also uses variable High, which is set as `highest (high, interval)`, just like I drew here:
[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDAxh.png)
Here is the code that I am trying to get to work:

```
plot(condition1 ? High : na, color=red, transp=transparency,  title="Do", linewidth=5)
plotshape(condition1 ? High : na, color=red, transp=transparency, style = shape.labeldown, location = location.belowbar, text = "Resistance "+High)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label.new()` for that

```
lbl = label.new(bar_index, your_plot_line, text = "Resistance" + "\n" + tostring(your_plot_line), xloc = xloc.bar_index, style = label.style_label_down, color = ..., textcolor = ...)
label.delete(lbl[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the label I ended up using, be aware it is pine script v4 only:

```
label1 = label.new(bar_index, High, text = "Resistance" + "\n" + tostring(High,'#.##'),style = label.style_label_up ,xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red, textcolor = color.white)
label.delete(label1[1])
```